# User Authentication with Cookies Only

Tags: authentication, cookies

I am planning to use only cookies (and not sessions) to authenticate users around the private section of my website. I want users to stay logged in indefinitely, unless they logout themselves. It will work like this:

**1.** Upon successful login I generate a random hash and store it as a HTTP cookie on the user (using SSL). I also store the hash in my database, along with the user id and the user's device.

**2.** Whenever a new page is requested I check to see if the user has a cookie. If he has I get the hash and search it in my database. If I find a match and the device is the same I assume it's the user and give the page. If I can't find the hash or the device changed I assume it's not the user and ask for login again.

**My question**: would this method be acceptable, security-wise? I can't see why this would be less secure than using sessions (keeping the users logged in in both cases), as in the end the risk is the same, which is having an attacker discover the hash to impersonate the user. My defense against this is tracking the users device, so the attacker would need to discover the hash and have the same device.

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is basically the session functionality offered by most languages/frameworks.

Just make sure your hash values don't use the time the user logged in as a source of entropy, ie. don't use h(username + login_time) because this could be brute forced fairly easily if the attacker knew the approximate login time.

What language / framework are you actually using? You'll find in most cases there's an option to use the session "functionality" with a persistent cookie (rather than a session one) which would save you implementing this from scratch and possibly creating additional security concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll be creating my own framework in PHP, since I need very few functionalities (authentication being one of them). This is also to learn the stuff along the way. I know that if I wanted to be more secure I should go with an established framework as it will probably have this stuff figured out.

Comment: To be fair, this is how the in-build session functionality is implemented in PHP too. If you set the cookie_lifetime to a value other than 0 it'll use a persistent cookie rather than a session one: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime also, if you need some but not all the components of an MVC framework I'd suggest taking components out of Zend. I don't use Zend primarily, but when I need some functionality like caching or session management in a legacy code-base I usually find it very easy to integrate Zend components.

Comment: I didn't know I could take Zend components separately. I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: You sure can, here's a brief intro: http://www.slideshare.net/shahar/zend-framework-components-for-nonframework-use